# What is the correct placement of an object pronoun's explicit pronoun?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Given a sentence containing a direct object like:

> Le enviaré las fotografías

if I want to clarify the pronoun as "usted", where do I put the explicit pronoun? Does it go before or after the direct object? Or can it go in either place?

In other words, which would I write?

> Le enviaré a usted las fotografías.

or

> Le enviaré las fotografías a usted.

Or are both of those sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: They both work.  I'm having trouble seeing a need for the explicit pronoun.  But I can certainly imagine that there could be situations where it would be helpful to leave it unambiguous.

Comment: I guess "enviaré a Ud." is one notch less pompous (i.e. more down to earth) to my ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in either of the positions, as well as others.  All of the following are considered correct:

- **A usted** le enviaré las fotografías.
- Le enviaré **a usted** las fotografías.
- Le enviaré las fotografías **a usted**.

As we add new elements, new possibilities open up:

- **A usted** le enviaré las fotografías mañana por correo electrónico.
- Le enviaré **a usted** las fotografías mañana por correo electrónico.
- Le enviaré las fotografías **a usted** mañana por correo electrónico.
- Le enviaré las fotografías mañana  **a usted** por correo electrónico.
- Le enviaré las fotografías mañana por correo electrónico **a usted** .

The differences in meaning can be barely perceptible (if they even exist, which is doubtful/would be unusual in many cases), but when placed first it often has a meaning of "to you (and not to someone else)".

Comment: Siempre me he preguntado si hay alguna regla general, como recuerdo que había en inglés. Entiendo que todas suenan bien, pero lo mismo en el _core_ del lenguaje hay algo ¿?

Comment: Thanks. If this "a" is essentially the preposition "to", the placement would seem to be the semantically-neutral difference in English between "To you, I will send the photographs", "I will send, to you, the photographs.", and "I will send the photographs to you." I was under the impression that the object pronoun "a" was something more abstract like the personal "a".

Comment: i prefer to omit the "usted" if there's no ambiguity between "you" or "him/her" 
this is because the formal pronoun "usted" is conjugated t he same way as "el/ella". in that case i switch to the informal pronoun "tu"

Comment: @PatrickDark actually, the same rule would apply for the direct object pronouns that take the *a personal*.  The (minor) catch is that while indirect objects allow for full redundancy, with a handful of exceptions, with direct objects you are *required* to use the pronoun and the explicit object if the explicit object comes before the verb, and you are prohibited from using the pronoun if it comes after.

Comment: Not sure which fits your idea better -- *doubtful* or *unusual* -- so I hope you'll check my edit and pick the one that reflects your idea.